# Besides Jesus, is there any other figure in the Bible that would claim that some of the prophecies in the Scriptures were about him?

Tags: biblical-basis, prophecy, prophets

Besides Jesus, is there any other figure in the Bible that would claim that some of the prophecies in the Scriptures were about him?

Comment: Which prophecies?  There are prophecies about Saul and David and Isaiah and Paul others.

Comment: @Mac'sMusings - Did Saul, David, Isaiah or Paul ever say that those were the prophecies exactly about them?

Comment: Now you are asking a different question.  Lots of people had prophecies made about them including Timothy.  To which prophecies are you alluding?

Comment: It's still the same question. "To which prophecies are you alluding?" - To any prophecies (if any) contained in the Scriptures that these people would themselves state that they were about them.

Comment: I'm curious as to what the thinking behind this question is, it seems an oddly specific yet insignificant thing to want to know who else "claimed" prophecies about themselves, not just simply who else was prophesied about

Comment: @IsaacMiddlemiss - Because it is one thing to be someone of whom the Bible doesn't specifically say anything. It is another thing to be someone of whom there is a prophecy in the Bible. And yet it is quite a special thing when there is someone who claims that a certain prophesy in the Bible was exactly about him. Judging from the replies I have received so far, it looks like there have been only two such personalities: Jesus and John the Baptist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Presumably Zerubbabel and Joshua?

Haggai and Zerubbabel both prophesied about Zerubbabel and Joshua to Zerubbabel and Joshua. If they had any sense at all, they must have acknowledged that it happened.

### David

A) There wasn't much denying it after Nathan said his piece about Uriah, and
B) Some of the psalms are both inspired and predict the future about David. Which makes David a prophet about David, the only one other than Jesus to manage such a thing.

### Nebuchadnezzar

Acknowledged the truth of Daniel's prophecy about his humiliation by madness.

### Jereboam, son of Nebat

Presumably would claim he was a prophesied king. But maybe not. He didn't seem convinced he would stay king, hence the calves.

Answer (score 6):

The below verses from the Gospel of John is where John the Baptist is quoting a prophecy about himself:

> John 1:19-23 (NIV) Now this was John’s testimony when the Jewish leaders in Jerusalem sent priests and Levites to ask him who he was. He did not fail to confess, but confessed freely, “I am not the Messiah.”
>
> They asked him, “Then who are you? Are you Elijah?”
>
> He said, “I am not.”
>
> “Are you the Prophet?”
>
> He answered, “No.”
>
> Finally they said, “Who are you? Give us an answer to take back to those who sent us. What do you say about yourself?”
>   John replied in the words of Isaiah the prophet, “I am the voice of one calling in the wilderness, ‘Make straight the way for the Lord.’”

John the Baptist quoted from Isa 40:3:

> Isa 40:3 (RSV) A voice cries:
>   “In the wilderness prepare the way of the Lord,
>       Make straight in the desert a highway for our God".
>
> Isa 40:3 (NASB) A voice is calling,
>   “Clear the way for the Lord in the wilderness;
>   Make smooth in the desert a highway for our God".
>
> Isa 40:3 (NKJV) The voice of one crying in the wilderness:
>   “Prepare the way of the Lord;
>   Make straight in the desert
>   A highway for our God".
>
> Isa 40:3 (TLB) Listen! I hear the voice of someone shouting, “Make a road for the Lord through the wilderness; make him a straight, smooth road through the desert".

Comment: This is what immediately came to my own mind. John the the Baptist stands out - _Verily I say unto you, Among them that are born of women there hath not risen a greater than John the Baptist_ Matthew 11:11.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander the Great. Not only does Daniel speak of his kingdom, but Job 20 prophesies his death:

```
Do you not know this from of old,
    since man was placed on earth,
5 that the exulting of the wicked is short,
    and the joy of the godless but for a moment?
6 Though his height mount up to the heavens,
    and his head reach to the clouds,
7 he will perish forever like his own dung;
    those who have seen him will say, ‘Where is he?’
8 He will fly away like a dream and not be found;
    he will be chased away like a vision of the night.
9 The eye that saw him will see him no more,
    nor will his place any more behold him.
10 His children will seek the favor of the poor,
    and his hands will give back his wealth.
11 His bones are full of his youthful vigor,
    but it will lie down with him in the dust.

12 “Though evil is sweet in his mouth,
    though he hides it under his tongue,
13 though he is loath to let it go
    and holds it in his mouth,
14 yet his food is turned in his stomach;
    it is the venom of cobras within him.
15 He swallows down riches and vomits them up again;
    God casts them out of his belly.
16 He will suck the poison of cobras;
    the tongue of a viper will kill him.
17 He will not look upon the rivers,
    the streams flowing with honey and curds.
18 He will give back the fruit of his toil
    and will not swallow it down;
from the profit of his trading
    he will get no enjoyment.
19 For he has crushed and abandoned the poor;
    he has seized a house that he did not build.

20 “Because he knew no contentment in his belly,
    he will not let anything in which he delights escape him.
21 There was nothing left after he had eaten;
    therefore his prosperity will not endure.
22 In the fullness of his sufficiency he will be in distress;
    the hand of everyone in misery will come against him.
23 To fill his belly to the full,
    God[a] will send his burning anger against him
    and rain it upon him into his body.
24 He will flee from an iron weapon;
    a bronze arrow will strike him through.
25 It is drawn forth and comes out of his body;
    the glittering point comes out of his gallbladder;
    terrors come upon him.
26 Utter darkness is laid up for his treasures;
    a fire not fanned will devour him;
    what is left in his tent will be consumed.
27 The heavens will reveal his iniquity,
    and the earth will rise up against him.
28 The possessions of his house will be carried away,
    dragged off in the day of God's[b] wrath.
29 This is the wicked man's portion from God,
    the heritage decreed for him by God.”
```

About twenty details of the death of Alexander the Great are found in this passage, including the circumstances of the start of his illness (at a party), his youth, most of his medical symptoms (abdominal and back pains, vomiting, fever, delirium, etc), the fate of his family (killed by one of his generals), and the fact that when buried, he would be encased in honey (which slows decay of corpses).

Comment: So where in the Bible does Alexander the Great claim that that prophesy was about him?

Comment: I assumed the question was speculative. However, when Alexander captured Judah, he was deterred from offering a pagan sacrifice on their altar when the Jewish priests informed him that their God decreed his conquest, which satisfied him.

Answer (score 0):

> Who says of Cyrus, ‘He is My shepherd, And he shall perform all My pleasure, Saying to Jerusalem, “You shall be built,” And to the temple, “Your foundation shall be laid.” ’  (Isaiah 44:28 NKJV)

> Thus says the Lord to His anointed, To Cyrus, whose right hand I have held— To subdue nations before him And loose the armor of kings, To open before him the double doors, So that the gates will not be shut.  (Isaiah 45:1 NKJV)

Isaiah's prophetic career, which began in 755 BC, was 200 years before Cyrus the Great became king of Persia in 559 BC.  Cyrus was the king who freed the Jews and returned the exiles and plunder from Babylon to Jerusalem, fulfilling Isaiah's prophecy.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: So where in the Bible does Cyrus claim that that prophesy was about him? He may have not even ever heard of it.

Comment: "Now in the first year of Cyrus king of Persia, that the word of the Lord by the mouth of Jeremiah might be fulfilled, the Lord stirred up the spirit of Cyrus king of Persia, so that he made a proclamation throughout all his kingdom, and also put it in writing, saying, 23 Thus says Cyrus king of Persia: All the kingdoms of the earth the Lord God of heaven has given me. And He has commanded me to build Him a house at Jerusalem which is in Judah. Who is among you of all His people? May the Lord his God be with him, and let him go up!" (2 Chronicles 36:22-23 NKJV)

Comment: Where do we see in these words that Cyrus was claiming that there was some prophecy in the Scriptures which was about him? He may have never even read the Scriptures, but only had his spirit stirred up by the Lord, which was, in fact, quite a common thing in the Old Testament times when God wanted to carry out His will using a Gentile king as a tool.

Comment: 1) I think you're splitting hairs.  2) A prophecy doesn't have to be acknowledged by the person who was the object of the prophecy.

Comment: @CPRouse - "A prophecy doesn't have to be acknowledged by the person who was the object of the prophecy" - Where did I say that it has to?

Comment: @brilliant You said, "So where in the Bible does Cyrus claim that that prophesy was about him? He may have not even ever heard of it."  Apparently I don't understand the purpose of that comment.  I took it to mean that you didn't think the prophecy was about Cyrus since he didn't acknowledge it as being about him.

Comment: Of course, I agree that the prophecy is about him. And I agree that that prophesy is a real and valid prophesy. It is just that my question is looking specifically for a prophesy, the object of which later claimed that that prophesy was about him.

Comment: @brilliant According to those tight parameters, nobody, including Jesus, fills the bill.  Nowhere was the arrival of Jesus Christ prophesied by the name "Jesus".  It was always aliases like "Emmanuel", "Prince of Peace", or "Wonderful Counselor".

Comment: The presence of the exact name in the prophecy was not one of the parameters. Quite often a prophecy doesn't give the name of the one who the prophecy is about.

Comment: @brilliant In that case, a number of Assyrian, Babylonian, and Egyptian kings/pharaohs were prophesied.  You could almost open Isaiah to any random page and find one.

Comment: Did any of those kings ever claim that those prophecies in Isaiah were about them?

Comment: @brilliant And now we've gone full circle.

Comment: Such have been the parameters of my question from the very start. Sorry, but if you keep trying to answer it while ignoring those parameters, I will have to bring you back to them. Otherwise, it won't be an answer to my question.

Comment: David: David, the second king of Israel, claimed that several prophecies were about him, including those related to his rise to power and his reign as king (2 Samuel 7:12-16).

    Jeremiah: Jeremiah, a prophet in the Old Testament, claimed that he was chosen by God before he was born and that he had been given the task of prophesying to the nations (Jeremiah 1:4-10).

    Daniel: Daniel, a prophet in the Old Testament, interpreted several prophecies related to the Babylonian and Persian empires and claimed that God had revealed these prophecies to him (Daniel 2:27-28).

Comment: John the Baptist: John the Baptist claimed that he was the fulfillment of the prophecy in Isaiah 40:3, which spoke of a voice calling in the wilderness to prepare the way of the Lord (John 1:23).

Paul: The apostle Paul claimed that he was chosen by God to be a minister to the Gentiles and that he had received revelations from God that were not previously known (Galatians 1:11-12).